# Parsing a single dimensional list into dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to parse a the following list format into a dict.

This represents 2 people, with 3 pieces of data for each person, firstname, lastname, & email.

```
data = [3, 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 2, 'jack', 'black', 'jb@example.com', 'jane', 'green', 'jg@examlpe.com']
```

data[0] is how many people fields are being sent. (3)

The next 3 items are the property names.

Before the actual person data starts, the 2 represents how many people are to follow.

I'm new to Python and I'm wondering if there's a slick way to do this. I feel like there's got to be a better way.

(untested code, just showing the only way i can think to approach it)

```
def formatPeople(self, data):
  param_count = data[0]
  keys = []
  pos = 1
  while pos <= param_count:
    keys.append(data[pos])
    pos += 1;

  people_count = int(data[pos])
  pos += 1
  people = []

  i = 0
  while i < people_count:
    people_data = {}
    for x in keys:
        people_data[keys[x]] = data[pos]
        pos += 1

    people.append(people_data)
  return people
```

Comment: A better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i disagree, you could say that about a ton of posts. (and maybe you do) ... not sure if you're the one that voted down, but that's sadly funny if you did.

Comment: Have a look at `itertools.groupby()` - it might be helpful for this task.

Comment: @Coder1 I don't downvote questions I vote to close. Also, said ton of posts might also not be a good fit for SO.

Comment: You and others who voted to close this are abusing the system.  This question totally falls within the FAQ link provided that tells me questions what questions generally relate to.  Good job degrading the quality of the site. There is a great answer provided here that will surely help future people looking for a solution to "a specific programming problem" or "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" for something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a good list to use iterators:

```
>>> i = iter(data)
>>> attr = [next(i) for x in range(next(i))]
>>> [{x:next(i) for x in attr} for y in range(next(i))]
[{'lastname': 'black', 'email': 'jb@example.com', 'firstname': 'jack'}, {'lastname': 'green', 'email': 'jg@examlpe.com', 'firstname': 'jane'}]
```

Comment: That's the functionality I was looking for.  I have a lot of data in this format I need to parse.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good job for list comprehension. One-liner too. :)

```
people = [{data[j]: data[data[0] * (i + 1) + j + 1] for j in xrange(1, data[0] + 1)} for i in xrange(0, data[data[0] + 1])]
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that the order of the Keys and Values would match?

Comment: That's irrelevant. There's no way to tell the difference between a first or last name so it's up to the user to get it right.